# struts2 jquery dynamic tree icon

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I want to assign tree icon through JSON data:

```
TreeNode nodes = new TreeNode();
String icon="/images/datebox_arrow.png";
nodes.setId("rootNode");
nodes.setTitle("Net Work");
nodes.setIcon(icon);
nodes.setChildren(new LinkedList<TreeNode>());
```

From the above code Id & Title working fine, icon is not working

in JSP file calling like bellow

```
<sjt:tree             
        rootNode="nodes" 
        nodeHref="%{echo}"                   
        nodeTitleProperty="title" 
        nodeIdProperty="id" 
        nodeHrefParamName="echo"
        childCollectionProperty="children" 
        cssStyle="border:none;background:white;"
       onClickTopics="treeClicked" 
        ></sjt:tree>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1:** You need to have json action

```
package com.common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery.tree.result.TreeNode;

public class JsonTreeData{
private List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

public String execute() {

    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
    node.setId("rootNode");
    node.setTitle("Net Work");
    node.setIcon("/images/datebox_arrow.png");
    node.setChildren(new LinkedList<TreeNode>());
    nodes.add(node);

    return "success";
}

public List<TreeNode> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

public void setNodes(List<TreeNode> nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}

}
```

Bind this action to url in `struts.xml`

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
  <action name="json-tree-data" 
       class="com.common.JsonTreeData">
       <result type="json" >

       </result>
  </action>
</package>
```

When you put this url in browser

> http:// localhost :8080/yourProjectName/json-tree-data

It should return this json

> {"nodes":[{"attr":{"id":"rootNode"},"children":[],"data":{"icon":"/images/datebox_arrow.png","title":"Net Work"},"icon":"/images/datebox_arrow.png","id":"rootNode","state":"closed","title":"Net Work","type":null}]}

**Alternative 2:** You can set icon via inline css on page

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-state-default  .ui-icon {
    background-image: url('images/datebox_arrow.png');
    background-size: 16px 16px;
}
.ui-state=hover {
    background-image: url('images/datebox_arrow.png');
    background-size: 16px 16px;
}
.ui-icon-document{
    background-position:center;
}
</style>
```